# Send date parameter from html form to controller in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am facing the below problem while passing date to controller, if I remove the date then its working correctly.

My html code is

```
<div class="form-group" id="all">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput3">Start date</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate" th:value="*{startDate}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="all">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="focusedInput4">End date</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate" th:value="*{endDate}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my Entity class is

```
@Column(name = "name")
private String courseName;

@Column(name = "semister")
private String semister;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY")
@Column(name = "startDate")
private Date startDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY")
@Column(name = "endDate")
private Date endDate;
```

after clicking on submit button, the following error occurs:

[image]

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing  this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 24 14:05:33 IST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Here is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class CourseScheduleController {

@Autowired
private CourseScheduleService courseScheduleService; 

@RequestMapping("/createCourse")
public ModelAndView getAllativities() {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("courseName", "");
    model.put("semister", "");
    model.put("startDate",null);
    model.put("endDate",null);
    return new ModelAndView("createCourse",model);
}

@RequestMapping("/saveCourse")
public String saveCourseSchedule(@ModelAttribute CourseBE courseBE){
    courseScheduleService.saveCourseSchedule(courseBE);
    return "redirect:/admin/createCourse";
}
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Replace 
`@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY")`

With 

`@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)`

Comment: Could you please send your Controller Class (Mapping methods)?

Comment: @ s.kwiotek, posted controller class
@ Abel Roussi . Chnaged but results in same erroe

Comment: why are you using the `*{ ... }` operator and not the `${ ... }`?.. show the whole html file (where is the submit button?) and the name of the thymeleaf template (is it `createCourse.html?`)..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should include a binder on controller:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");

        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String value) {
                try {
                    setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(value));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    setValue(null);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a binder in your controller will allow the binding from your form to your model.

```
 @InitBinder
 public void initDateBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"), true));
 }
```

Should do the trick and convert your input string from your form in date.

If you are using the `input type="date"` I think you'll have no choice in the [pattern date](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html).
If you want more flexibility in the pattern just change the input type to the text one and adapt the format's pattern to whatever you like.

You should use th:field in your html markup for the binding to mork like :

```
<input th:field="*{startDate}"
```

and be sure that your form has something like `<form th:object="${courseBE}"` to define the bean use to bind your form.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

To the properties file. It will help with detailed logging regarding HTTP errors.